# How to specify a write concern for `findOneAndUpdate` with MongoDB's node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It seems like `findAndModify` which has a `w` option is deprecated but the replacement method `findOneAndUpdate` doesn't have a `w` option.

Comment: `uodateOne` and `updateMany` methods have the `w` option and valid. You can also specify the `writeConcern` option when creating the `MongoClient`:  [URI Connection Settings](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/connecting/connection-settings/).

Comment: `findAndModify` is not depreciated, it's still alive and kicking, see the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/index.html)

Comment: @OTZ The MongoDB NodeJS driver's API method _is_ deprecated.

Comment: This seems like an omission in the documentation: `writeConcern` _can_ be specified for a `findOneAndUpdate` operation, you can verify this from the mongo shell.